# Div String replacement using RegEx

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am using the following code :

```
breakContent = breakContent.replace(/<div>/g, ' <div>');
```

Here `breakContent` is a string that contains html code. I need to provide space before `div` tag.The above code works fine for `div` without any attribute like `id`, `style`,etc...

So what I need is the working code including attributes in `div` tag...

I tried the below code..but it does not give space before `div` and instead it replace the `div` with space

```
 breakContent = breakContent.replace(/<div\s*[\/]?>/gi, " ");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change it to:

```
breakContent = breakContent.replace(/<div/g, ' <div');
```

Removing the trailing `>` will allow for `<div>` tags with attributes.

EDIT: Of course, this could pick up text that isn't actually a `<div>` tag, if you have text matching `<div` that isn't a tag.